# how to run ipad phone gap app on device and send it to others

Tags: xcode4, cordova

I have a ipad phone gap app i want that app should also run on my clients device how may do this as we do normal by adhoc distribution and send ipa file but this is an phonegap app so how may send this and run on any device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Test flight (http://testflightapp.com) to distribute enterprise ad-hocs, or you can use phonegap build (http://build.phonegap.com) and then send the generated qr codes to your clients, so they can install the builds.